# Recharts issue with gaps between Bars

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, recharts

I am using **BarChart** from the **Recharts** library, however I am facing the issue while adding the space between bars.
I have tried to use the attribute `barGap={20}` `barCategoryGap={20}`, however it doesn't seem to be working.

```
  <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={230}>
  <BarChart layout="vertical" width="100%" height={600} data={data} barGap={100} barCategoryGap={-20}
        margin={{top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20}}>
      <CartesianGrid stroke='#f5f5f5'/>
      <XAxis interval={0} type="number"/>
      <YAxis width={180} dx={-10} interval={0} dataKey="name" type="category"/>
      <Tooltip cursor={{fill: '#fff'}}/>
      <Legend/>

      <Bar dataKey='pv' barSize={18} fill='#f19135' radius={[0,20,20,0]} background={{fill: "#FFF"}}/>
   </BarChart>
   </ResponsiveContainer>
```

Comment: Can you please attach the whole code snippet so that we can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't work for you because you specified `barSize` in your `<Bar>`.

> The width or height of each bar. If the barSize is not specified, the size of the bar will be calculated by the barCategoryGap, barGap and the quantity of bar groups.

If you remove `barSize` you will be able to change gap between your Bars with `barCategoryGap` property. Either with this `barCategoryGap="10%"`(percents) or this `barCategoryGap={10}`(pixels) syntax

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6aw9ezjL/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the latest version.