# How to minimize gaps between bars without changing their width

Tags: javascript, recharts

Let's say I have this chart:
[image]

I need to minimize gaps between the bars.

I'm aware about this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55215557/recharts-issue-with-gaps-between-bars),but if you provide `barCategoryGap` property, the width of the bars will  be increased.

U need to end up with smth like that:
[image]

So, there should be no gaps (1px is ok) between the bars and bars should have 10-15px width

I have tried to change next properties:`barCategoryGap, barGap, barSize` but nothing helps.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-field-zcyo2?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but after playing around a bit this is what i got. I notice you have the `barSize` prop in the `<Bar>` component.
What i've got so far.

```
<div>
  <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
   <BarChart data={data} barGap="1%">
     <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
     <XAxis dataKey="name" />
     <YAxis />
     <Tooltip />
     <Legend />
     <Bar dataKey="pv" fill="#8884d8" />
   </BarChart>
  </ResponsiveContainer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! try to add `barSize={20}` to the `Bar` component. That is the width I want them to have. Yo will see that there is still a gap :(

Comment: Try ```barSize={50}``` and remove ```barCategoryGap="1" barGap="2" ```